# Calculate time difference between value in table and now

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm doing a report for my Merchants data to find out the number of years or months since they started their business. So in my table I have a BusinessStartDate, but I want to find out the years or month since they start their business for example:

```
BusinessStartdate           No of years or Months

2003-02-01 00:00:00.000     9
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why people that ask something about sql *never* puts what database engine is using ? So, are you using MySql, SQL-Server, oracle.. ?

Comment: What good is a column returning a number of years **or** months but not specifying which? Can you be a little clearer in your requirement please?

Comment: And also important is the precise method of counting.

Comment: A column that can have years or months is a terrible idea. Why not just months?, and if you need years then you can have them on another column

Comment: @Lamak I think that is the output, not something that is stored.

Comment: I want to calculate off of BusinessStartdate. I'm going to put that on another column.

Comment: @user1440697 then I agree with Lamak. You should not *store* this redundant piece of information. Why do you need to store it when you can always calculate it at query time? And when you store it, you'll need to run a sweeping update across the *entire table* every month, otherwise it will be incorrect!

Comment: `select case when RAND()>0.5 then DATEDIFF(MONTH, businessstartdate, GETDATE()) else 
DATEDIFF(YEAR, businessstartdate, GETDATE()) end` ?

Comment: @podiluska please don't put code in a comment, it is entirely unreadable.

Comment: @user1440697 why would you want to show the months *or* years? Leave it up to the reader to decide what `9` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case
    when datediff(mm, BusinessStartDate, current_timestamp) > 12
    then datediff(yy, BusinessStartDate, current_timestamp)
    else datediff(mm, BusinessStartDate, current_timestamp)
end
```

Note my comment beneath the answer about method of counting. This version doesn't correspond to what we normally think of in terms of anniversaries. The expression below is a bit closer to normal so you can use it for comparison. There are plenty of other answers that address the problem of birthdays and age.

```
case
    when datediff(mm, BusinessStartDate, current_timestamp) > 12
    then datediff(dd, BusinessStartDate, current_timestamp) / 365
    else datediff(dd, BusinessStartDate, current_timestamp) / 30
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT BusinessStartDate,
  DATEDIFF(MONTH, BusinessStartDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  FROM dbo.table_name;
```

Comment: @AaronBetrand . . . is there an advantage to using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of getdate()?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - standards - it's more portable across database systems (of course, when it's inside a non standard `DATEDIFF`, the point is moot)

Comment: @GordonLinoff just preference / habit, since `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is ANSI standard. Same reason I use `<>` and not `!=` for inequality... if there are no other advantages, I stick with the standard.

Comment: I still don't understand the part where op says that he wants **years or months**. In the example that he posted, the `9` is representing years.

Comment: @Lamak I've posted a question on why he wants the end user to have to decipher what `9` means.